# How to update DynamoDB item by searching on GSI primary key?

Tags: dynamodb

Table has these columns on DynamoDB:

- primaryKey
- sortKey
- GSI_primaryKey
- data

And there is GSI added with primary key **GSI_primaryKey** and sort key on **primaryKey**

How to update column **data** if I have only the value of the GSI_primaryKey?

With NodeJS document client.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I found out is I need to get the item by GSI and then using primaryKey and sortKey update the item and cannot update item using GSI only.